# docker login on private nexus => Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://ip:port/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found

Tags: docker, nexus

I try to push a docker image to my private Nexus 3 registry.

Before to push, i try to authenticate doing : `docker login nexus_host:nexus_port`

But i got the following error message :

> Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://*nexus_host*:*nexus_port*/v2/ failed
>   with status: 404 Not Found

My Nexus use HTTP, so add it in docker insecure registries list.

- Nexus version : Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.9.0-01
- Docker version : 17.09.1-ce (Windows 10)

EDIT (08/03/2018) :

I use a hosted docker repository. Should i use a HTTP connector ?

**Repo Configuration :**
Format : docker
Type : hosted
URL : http://192.168.0.90:8082/repository/docker-repo/
HTTP connector port : 1111

**Login attempts :**

`docker login 192.168.0.90:8082`
=> Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://192.168.0.90:8082/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found

`docker login 192.168.0.90:1111`
=> Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.0.90:1111/v2/: dial tcp 192.168.0.90:1111: getsockopt: connection refused

Comment: i've just tried on a debian machine => same result

Comment: What type of docker repository is being used?  You can only push to a hosted docker repository, push to a group or proxy won't work.

Comment: @rseddon
Thanks for your help. I use a hosted docker repository. I updated the topic description because i tried with or without a HTTP connector and error messages are not the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct command to login into your docker repository is `docker login 192.168.0.90:1111`, because you've enabled HTTP connector on port `1111`.

Please make sure that you have checked *Force basic authentication* in your docker repository settings and for `docker login` use the same credentials as you do to access your instance of Nexus Repository Manager.

If the above doesn't help, then you should focus on what's causing the connection to be refused - please check if there are any firewalls between you and the Nexus blocking port `1111` (your docker repository connector port).

Comment: I manage to login on port 1111. The problem was that my Nexus was in a docker container and port 1111 was not exposed... Newbie mistake ! Thank you, Dawid !

Comment: Another issue I had was not adding `localhost:5000` to my insecure registries within my Docker Daemon config...

Comment: @Loïc, I have the same issue. I am trying to expose the port for HTTP connector. But that port is still not open inside the nexus container. How did you open it?

Comment: Rerun it, add another `-p`. For example ` docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8123:8123`

Comment: I am running nexus as service on windows on local machine where docker desktop also installed. trying to connect via docker login to nexus repo always fails with below error.  "Error response from daemon: Get "http://127.0.0.1:8060/v2/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8060: connect: connection refused
". I did all settings mentioned in this post on nexus repo for hosted repo. Also tried with completely disabling windows defender firewall, but still fails. I could give a call to localhost:8060 with curl, it gives some http response.

Answer (score 4):

I have struggled with this problem for a couple of days

I write the correct steps here to solve the problem

1- You should add two ports when running nexus image as below:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 --name nexus sonatype/nexus3
```

2- After running the nexus, use the admin password and sign in to the UI

3- Go to Settings > Repositories and select `Create Repository`. then select `docker(hosted)` and fill required data as below image

[image]

4- Go to Settings > Realms and select the options as below image

[image]

5- Don't forget to `Save` changes

6- Now you can login docker to the nexus with username and password

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, very descriptive. I am running Nexus from a compose file and I was using the container name: nexus:8081. Until I found your post :) I opened another port for pushing 8085.

`docker tag <name> 127.0.0.1:8085/java_test`
`docker push 127.0.0.1:8085/java_test`

This worked for me!

Comment: @Rodyb I am glad that your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

When you run a container in your host the only way to communicate with your application (except get bash from container) is the ports you exposed before the container run.

You just need to expose your selected port before run your container with this command:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 --name nexus sonatype/nexus3
```

First port(8081) use to nexus itself and second port (8082) use to http connector in configuration.

That's it!

Here is a good guide on this subject:
https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2016/06/09/create-a-private-docker-registry/